# Hold remainder of shell script commands until PBS qsub array job completes

Tags: shell, wait, chaining, qsub

I am **very** new to shell scripting, and I am trying to write a shell pipeline that submits multiple `qsub` jobs, but has several commands to run in between these qsubs, which are contingent on the most recent job completing. I have been researching multiple ways to try and hold the shell script from proceeding after submission of a `qsub` job, but none have been successful.

The simplest chunk of code I can provide to illustrate the issue is as follows:

```
THREADS=`wc -l < list1.txt`
qsub -V -t 1-$THREADS firstjob.sh
echo "firstjob.sh completed"
```

There are obviously other lines of code after this that are actually contingent on firstjob.sh finishing, but I have omitted them here for clarity. I have tried the following methods of pausing/holding the script:

1) Only using `wait`, which is supposed to stop the script until all background programs are completed. This pushed right past the `wait` and printed the `echo` statement to the terminal while the array job was still running. My guess is this is occurring because once the `qsub` job is submitted, is exits and `wait` thinks it has completed?

```
qsub -V -t 1-$THREADS firstjob.sh

wait

echo "firstjob.sh completed"
```

2) Setting the job to a variable, echoing that variable to submit the job, and using the the entire job ID along with `wait` to pause. The echo command should wait until all elements of the array job have completed.The error message is shown following the code, within the code block.

```
job1=$(qsub -V -t 1-$THREADS firstjob.sh)
echo "$job1"

wait $job1

echo "firstjob.sh completed"

####ERROR RECEIVED#### 
-bash: wait: `4585057[].cluster-name.local': not a pid or valid job spec
```

3) Using the `-sync y` for `qsub`. This should prevent it from exiting the `qsub` until the job is complete, acting as an effective pause...I had hoped. Error in comment after the commands. For some reason it is not reading the -sync option correctly?

```
qsub -V -sync y -t 1-$THREADS firstjob.sh

echo "firstjob.sh completed"

####ERROR RECEIVED####
qsub: script file 'y' cannot be loaded - No such file or directory
```

4) Using a dummy shell script (the dummy just makes an empty file) so that I could use the `-W depend=afterok:` option of `qsub` to pause the script. This again pushes right past to the *echo* statement without any pause for submitting the dummy script. Both jobs get submitted, one right after the other, no pause.

```
job1=$(qsub -V -t 1-$THREADS demux.sh)
echo "$job1"

check=$(qsub -V -W depend=afterok:$job1 dummy.sh) 
echo "$check"

echo "firstjob.sh completed"
```

Some further details regarding the script:

- Each job submission is an array job.
- The pipeline is being run in the terminal using a command resembling the following, so that I may provide it with 3 inputs:  **source Pipeline.sh -r list1.txt -d /workingDir/ -s list2.txt**
- I am certain that the firstjob.sh has not actually completed running because I see them in the queue when I use `showq`.

Perhaps there is an easy fix in most of these scenarios, but being new to all this, I am really struggling. I have to use this method in 8-10 places throughout the script, so it is really hindering progress. Would appreciate any assistance. Thanks.

**POST EDIT 1**

Here is the code contained in firstjob.sh...though doubtful that it will help. Everything in here functions as expected, always produces the correct results.

```
\#! /bin/bash
\#PBS -S /bin/bash
\#PBS -N demux
\#PBS -l walltime=72:00:00
\#PBS -j oe
\#PBS -l nodes=1:ppn=4
\#PBS -l mem=15gb

module load biotools
cd ${WORKDIR}/rawFQs/

INFILE=`head -$PBS_ARRAYID ${WORKDIR}${RAWFQ} | tail -1`
BASE=`basename "$INFILE" .fq.gz`

zcat $INFILE | fastx_barcode_splitter.pl --bcfile ${WORKDIR}/rawFQs/DemuxLists/${BASE}_sheet4splitter.txt --prefix ${WORKDIR}/fastqs/ --bol --suffix ".fq"
```

Comment: please edit your Q to include relavent code inside of `firstjob.sh` AND indicate where you are using back-grounded processes that will respond to `wait`. Good first Q. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks shellter. I am not entirely sure what you mean by the second part of your comment, could you elaborate a bit? "Processes that respond to `wait`"?

Comment: Yeah, oops, I realize now that you are passing jobs to `qsub` and that it is managing forking off sub-processes (I'm assuming), so there won't necessarily be an `&` involved. But that means using `wait` won't help you. The only thing I can think of is to have your `qsub` job write unique flag-files when a step has finished, and then have your script wait for those files to appear. Extra credit for flag files that include status info (recs processed, errors, warnings, etc). As there are very few followers for `qsub` here, I would look for a qsub specific support forum. Good luck!

Comment: maybe you need `-sync=y` ? I would follow up with `qsub` community about "does `-sync` work as I need". Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried using `-sync y`, and that worked for me, so good idea there... Not sure what's different about your setup.

But a couple other things you could try involve your main script knowing the status of the `qsub` jobs you're running. One idea is that you could have your main script check the status of your job using `qstat` and wait until it finishes before proceeding.

Alternatively, you could have the first job write to a file as its last step (or, as you suggested, set up a dummy job that waits for the first job to finish). Then in your main script, you can test to see whether that file has been written before going on.